# How do I change the keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard is behaving weirdly.  I suppose my keyboard layout which was US by default has been changed to another format.  Also a very strange sound is coming from my laptop every time when its booting.  Please help me.

Comment: Is there a small keyboard icon on the right side of the top panel? If so, what do you see if you click on it? Please edit the original question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your keyboard layout to your's desired one.type as keyboard in your unity dash or open system settings , there you will find keyboard layout option .click it to open and in that window ,click at layouts and there you can set your layout .for more information you can have a look at the image .[image]