# My keyboard is screwed up

Tags: keyboard, inspiron, 9.10

I've had Karmic installed on my computer for a few days now, and now I'm noticing that when I press keys on my keyboard, sometimes they either don't register, or they register an extra 20 times. 
Like for example, typing 'a' might return 'aaaaaaaaaaa'. I had this same problem back when I was running a newer version of ubuntu. (I downgraded because my Dell Inspiron 1501 is more compatible with 9.10). 
I'm not sure if this is because my laptop's keyboard driver is messed up, or if it's just a dirty keyboard. (It seems clean though). 
I haven't had this problem when I use an external keyboard.

FYI: Typing this question was brutal.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This may help you. [How do I change my keyboard layout](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180001/how-do-i-change-the-keyboard-layout)

Answer (score 0):

If it only happens on the attached/embedded keyboard it most likely is your laptop's fault. You could test this by using a different OS or inserting a Ubuntu Live CD, to see if perhaps any of your programs/drivers are causing an issue. But since it doesn't happen on external keyboards I’m sure its the laptop.

Comment: Well, how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on your particular type of laptop, I can't say what would fix it. If it were a desktop I would say to replace it. You could try to take it apart to remove the keyboard panel and see if there is any obvious damage, dust, or other particles. You may try to get a warranty from Dell, although I’m not sure what your or their warranty is. Also you could take it to a laptop repair store, as it is a hardware issue and not a software issue.