# Keyboard functions got swapped

Tags: keyboard

I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my sony laptop. Everything works fine. I have a minor issue:

1. @ key got swapped with "
2. ~ key got swapped with some other key

Kindly suggest how to handle this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/180001/94635

Comment: Did you by any chance hit shift + Caps Lock? That switches the language.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. To solve this:

1. Go to Keyboard Layout.
2. Remove the previous setting. For example: remove English[UK].
3. Add English[US].

I hope this will help you.